# python maya: affect groups of nodes

Tags: python, maya

I'm not quite sure where the problem is in this script. What I've done is this....
I have a scene with 2 curves. Each curve has three spheres linked to it.

I select the curves and run the script. It craps out and says I've got objects with matching names?

[image: Setup]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(selection=True, type='dagNode')

# groups of ![enter image description here][1]nodes to be exported out
nodeBundles = []

for n in selection:
    # list the children nodes
    children = cmds.listRelatives(n, allDescendents=True, noIntermediate=True, fullPath=True, type="dagNode", path=True)

    # list the transform nodes to each child node
    childrenTransforms = maya.cmds.listRelatives(children, type='transform', parent=True)

    # append each set of children to a unique array and then append to main array
    nodeBundles.append(childrenTransforms)

    # select the transform nodes
    # cmds.select(childrenTransforms)


# MXS cache out each bundle of nodes
for n in nodeBundles:
    cmds.select(clear=True)
    cmds.xform(n, absolute=True, t=[0,0,10])
    print n
```

FIXED CODE:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(selection=True, type='dagNode')

# groups of ![enter image description here][1]nodes to be exported out
nodeBundles = []

for n in selection:
    # list the children nodes
    children = cmds.listRelatives(n, allDescendents=True, noIntermediate=True, fullPath=True, type="dagNode", path=True)

    # list the transform nodes to each child node
    # childrenTransforms = maya.cmds.listRelatives(children, type='transform', parent=True)
    childrenTransforms = maya.cmds.listRelatives(children, type='transform', parent=True, fullPath=True)

    # append each set of children to a unique array and then append to main array
    nodeBundles.append(childrenTransforms)

    # select the transform nodes
    # cmds.select(childrenTransforms)


# MXS cache out each bundle of nodes
for n in nodeBundles:
    cmds.select(clear=True)
    cmds.xform(n, r=True, t=[0,0,10])
    print n
```

By adding a list inside of a list I can then iterated based on groups of children. is this the correct method of doing so then?

```
nodes = []

for item in cmds.ls(sl=True, type = 'transform'):
    descendants = cmds.listRelatives(ad=True, ni=True, f=True) or []
    # nodes += descendants  # append the list, not insert it

    nodes.append(descendants)

val = 1
for grp in nodes:
    for n in grp:
        cmds.select(clear=True)
        offset = val * 10
        print offset
        cmds.xform(n, r=True, t=[0,0,offset])

    val += 1
```

Comment: might help to see the actual error message, possibly the stack trace or at least the line where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your scene or error message, my assumption is you have multiple nodes of the same name. Because Maya uses strings, it can't tell the difference between `pSphere1` and... `pSphere1`

From the documentation on [`listRelatives`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/listRelatives.html), use the argument `fullPath`:

> Return full pathnames instead of object names.

Like this:

```
    childrenTransforms = maya.cmds.listRelatives(children, type='transform', parent=True, fullPath=True)
```

Assuming the error was in the last `cmds.xform`, this should make those transforms unambiguous (i.e. `|group1|pSphere1`)

Comment: You were correct. I got it working now. But I noticed that the parent 'curve' gets adjust with the xform command. What I'm trying to do is get all the children of the 'curve' and offset them using the xform command. I've updated the code above.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: When i run the script it applies the xform command to the curve. I only want it to affect the children of the curve, not the curve.

Answer (score 0):

listRelatives will work on selected objects if nothing is specified, so you can get the subnodes (with full paths) like this:

```
descendants = cmds.listRelatives(ad=True, ni=True, f=True) # f=True = long paths
```

If you were trying to use 'dagNode' to filter between shapes and geometry, it wont' work: dagNode will return both transforms and shapes. You can use 'geometryShape' to get only shapes:

```
descendant_shapes = cmds.listRelatives(ad=True, ni = True, f=True)
```

but in your case that would return the curveShape as well. You could filter out the curve with:

```
descendants = cmds.ls(descendants, type= surfaceShape, l=True) # l=True keeps long paths
```

Also: in you code you are passing lists-of-lists into nodeBundles, which Maya won't like. You should flatten the list by adding items one at a time:

```
nodes = []
for item in cmds.ls(sl=True, type = 'transform'):
    descendants = cmds.listRelatives(ad=True, ni=True, f=True) or []
    nodes += descendants  # append the list, not insert it

for n in nodes:
   cmds.select(clear=True)
   cmds.xform(n, r=True, t=[0,0,10])
```

Comment: @ steve, I was doing the list inside of a list so i could then iterate based on the different sets of child nodes. Check out my code below.

Comment: I placed it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Your update will move each group by a multiple of 10 in Z - is that what you want?  You're also moving them absolutely : the first group will go to 0,0,0,  the second to 0,0,10, and so on.  Do you want relative moves?

Comment: No I'm purposing moving them in multiple of 10 on the Z. That is exactly what I want to do. I was not sure if put lists inside of lists were the proper way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to use the same command on multiple items, either select them first and the use the command with no argumants, OR use the command with the cmd(*args) format. most maya commands don't like lists as arguments, but *args converts that to something maya sees as a group of arguments

Comment: I understand what your saying. This approach of an array inside of an array is a common method scene inside tools and I was unsure how to properly do it in Maya using python. I'll have to look into the method you have describe in the previous comment to further understand and see an example of what you are explaining. Unless you have something handy you wouldn't mind showing me.